# In QFT, how does matter field excitations create Macroscopic world having different behavior?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Is the answer similar to that of classical Quantum Mechanics: Decohrence? If yes, how does that work? I am unable to picture that with QFT. Is there any analogy between Matter Field (of QFT) and Matter Wave (of QM)?